# "The" before a noun shows that what is referred to is already known to the speaker

Tags: articles

> *The* before a noun shows that what is referred to is already known to the **speaker**, listener, **writer** and/or reader (it is the definite article) ... [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/a-an-and-the)

There are a lot of examples when the noun is already known to the **listener**:

> I watched **the** movie you recommended.

Both of them (speaker and listener) know the movie, The listener know it because he recommended it.

Also there are a lot of examples  in **reader** case:

> Once when a lion was asleep, a little mouse began running up and down on him. This soon awakened **the** lion ...

The lion mentioned before so the writer and the reader know which lion.

My question: What the dictionary mean by it is already known to the *speaker* or  *writer*? It would be great if there is some examples in these cases.

Comment: Suppose your friend had just said *I watched the movie*. If you already knew *which* movie she meant, (because you'd been talking about it a lot yesterday), that would be fine. Note that if you *didn't* remember, you might reasonably reply: ***What** movie?* - but she'd probably come back with something like ***You know!** The one we talked about yesterday!* (showing that at the earlier time, she at least *believed* that you knew what *the* referred to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The* can indicate to the hearer/reader that the speaker/writer has a specific instance in mind which she is ***about to define.*** For instance:

> I just saw **the** woman **who wrote that article**.

Here the speaker knows which woman she's talking about, but the hearer doesn't know which woman is meant until he hears **who wrote that article**.

And in fiction it is quite common for an author to introduce characters or situations with *the* as if the reader had already encountered them. For instance, Virginia Woolf's story "The Window" begins like this:

> "Yes, of course, if it's fine tomorrow," said Mrs. Ramsay. "But you'll
>   have to be up with the lark," she added.
>
> To her son these words conveyed an extraordinary joy, as if it were
>   settled, the expedition were bound to take place, and the wonder to which
>   he had looked forward, for years and years it seemed, was, after a night's
>   darkness and a day's sail, within touch.

Here the son knows what ***the*** expedition and ***the*** wonder are, and of course Woolf does too; but the reader doesn't. This has the effect of putting the reader in the middle of things and excites his desire to find out what the expedition and the wonder are.